# Android Webview Property - setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)

Tags: android, properties, webview

The **setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)** property is included in API level 16 and tThe default value of this proprty is **true** for API level **ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1** and below, and **false** for API level **JELLY_BEAN** and above. I have developed one android application which **runs from API 8 to 16**. Now, I need to set this webview settings property common from API 8 to API 16. How can I set this property.?